# I need help on creating a custom aggregate in last row of Oracle APEX 21.2 IG

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a simple sql that I am trying to add a custom aggregate by taking the sum of two columns and dividing the values against each other. Here is a planned equation

round((sum(col1)/sum(col2))*100,2) = new_col_footer

Doing this in a query would be easy with a union all but will not work in this case due to if a end user starts filtering the report, that union all calculated row could not reflect or correctly or become filtered out from view. Here is a screen shot of what I am trying to do. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

[What I am trying to show as ig is filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCCOV.png)

I tried applying some of the agg functions but it appears by default an interactive grid does not have a way to accomplish this by default.

Comment: I don't think this is possible the way you are suggesting it. Have a look at the ig cookbook (version 6 - for 19.2, just google it, you'll find it on John Snyders' blog). There is an example page "Dynamic Column Total". It works fine when user filters. I'd use that as a starting point.

Comment: Include the text in the external URL in your question in triple backticks. URLs (that may eventually go away) will make your question unintelligible to future visitors. This makes your question broken (it may make some sense now, but it likely won't make sense in a week/month/year)

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I am going through the IG cookbook and seeing if anything makes since. I will update this question with if I find a solution or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Give IDs to your report(report_id) and columns(col_1, col_2 and
   col_3) first.
2. Then create a Dynamic Action for the report, using `Event > After Refresh`.
3. Then add in True action of `Execute JavaScript Code` and below codes

#If you are using Interactive Report;

```
    var col_1=0, col_2=0, col_3=0;
    $('#report_id .a-IRR-table tbody tr:last-child').each(function(){
        col_1 = $(this).find('td[headers="col_1"] .a-IRR-aggregate-value').text();
        col_1 = parseInt(col_1.replace(/,/g,''),10);
        
        col_2 = $(this).find('td[headers="col_2"] .a-IRR-aggregate-value').text();
        col_2 = parseInt(col_2.replace(/,/g,''),10);

        col_3 = (col_1/col_2)*100;
        $(this).find('td[headers="col_3"]').text(col_3);
    });
```

If you are using Classic Report, update the CSS class accordingly.

Comment: This is sweet. I was trying to do it in an Interactive Grid but an Interactive report works also. Thank you so much!!